# ngRoute Conflicts with Animated Scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My ng-route conflicts with the animated scroll that I have implemented on my web page:

Here's my scroll element:

```
<a href="#one" class="goto-next scrolly">Next</a>
```

where "`#one"` is the section ID where to scroll to goto-next is an image class and scrolly is for the smooth scroll animation.

Here's my ngRoute config:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngRoute'])

.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl : 'templates/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            // route for the about page
            .when('/whatwedo', {
                templateUrl : 'templates/whatwedo.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .when('/tryus', {
                templateUrl : 'templates/tryus.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            .when('/pricing', {
                templateUrl : 'templates/pricing.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })
            .when('/videos', {
                templateUrl : 'templates/videos.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })
            .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/home'
    });
})
```

Whenever I click the scroll element , n-groute routes it to the default webpage ,and instead of scrolling , it routes to the default webpage.Can't fix it.Please help.

**EDIT**: Used ui.router instead of ngRoute but still the scroll animation (auto scroll on button click) doesn't work.

Comment: I already tried that .... but it does not animate-scrolls but directly jumps to the link.

Comment: Ok that's true. Personally I recommend [this](https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll) one, it's really simple and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in router provider in Angular isn't much perfect and it has a lot of issues like the one you are having, so I don't recommend to use it. You could look at `ui-router` as this will resolve the issue you have, since it implements a state-like machine for manipulating routes/links, it's much more flexible and convenient.

The reason you have that kind of problem is because it appends `#one` in the url and by nature Angular-router is observing the changes and it will automatically process the new URl, which would likely say that the page is not found.

See the [README](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and look at the examples provided.

Hopefully this would resolve your issue.